# Use of indicator function for conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Consider three random variables: $T \in [0,1] $, $S\in \{ l,h \}$, and $K\in [0,1]$.

We know that (i) $K$ is independent of $T$ and $S$; (ii) $T \sim U[0,1]$; and (iii) $\Pr[S=h \mid T=t]=\pi(t)$ with $\pi'(\cdot)>0$.

In this context, I came across the following statement (where $I$ is the indicator function):

$$\begin{align}
&E[T \times I(T>a,K<b) \mid S=h]\\[8pt]
&=E[T \times I(T>a \mid S=h)]\cdot\Pr[K<b)]\\[8pt]
&=\left(\frac{\int^1_a t\pi(t) dt}{\int^1_0 \pi(u) du}\right)\Pr[K<b]\end{align}$$

I want to know if the first step makes sense and if there is an abuse of notation. I understand from the last equality that $E[T \times I(T>a \mid S=h)]$ refers to the expectation of a random variable with the distribution of $T\mid S\!=\!s$ truncated at $T>a$, (and multiplied by the probability of truncation).

Comment: What are $S$ and $Z$, one of them is just a typo? What is $I_{A|C}$?

Comment: @Ilya: yes, that was a typo -just corrected it. $I_{A|C}=I(A|C)$ Not quite sure if that makes sense (the notation is new to me)

Comment: I have never seen such notation. Conditioning is only defined for probabilities/expectations usually. Unfortunately unless your clarify what does $I(A|C)$ mean, it's hard to help you

Comment: @EOO : You wrote "A|\text{ }", using \text{ } for spacing.  But "A\mid B" does it: $\displaystyle A\mid B$.

Comment: @Ilya: I see... well, I found this in some lecture notes discussing a truncated expectation; I'm thinking they have in mind an event defined through an ancillary random variable, say $Z<t$, where $Z$ has the distribution of T given S

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks. And what is the trick for arranging the equations vertically? Looks neater!

Comment: The "trick" can be seen by clicking on "edit" and seeing what I wrote.  Use "align", and a double backslash for the end of the line, and things like [8pt] for adding more space between lines, and an ampersand for lining up the "=".

Comment: *I found this in some lecture notes*... Which ones?

Comment: To be more precise, the notes were not given to me on a "lecture", but rather correspond to a suggested proof sent by my supervisor. The document is not public, but I will edit the question to match the exact notation on the notes, in case I interpreted it wrongly. If it still does not make sense I'll ask him directly and correct or delete the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @EOO: that's good. Please ping me whenever you edit the text

Comment: @Ilya: I edited the question. Hopefully it is now clearer where it comes from. Thanks

Comment: The first and the third expressions coincide but the second one is a mystery, with respect to notations as well as to its role in the proof.

Comment: @Did: Thanks. So the last line does follow from the first? In that case I suppose the second line is just a typo or an abuse of notation (or both). Could you please clarify how the last line obtains from the first? -Like I said, I believe the last term is the expectation of a random variable with the distribution of $T\mid S\!=\!s$ truncated at $T>a$ and multiplied by the probability of truncation, but I don't really see how to get there from the first line...

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce the events $A=[T\gt a]$, $B=[K\lt b]$ and $H=[S=h]$. 
Then, by definition, 
$$
\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_B\mid H)=\frac{\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_B\mathbf 1_H)}{\mathbb P(H)}.
$$
Since $K$ is independent of $(T,S)$, $\mathbf 1_B$ is independent of $T\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_H$ hence the numerator is $\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_H)\mathbb P(B)$. Furthermore, $\mathbb P(H\mid T)=\pi(T)$, hence
$$
\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_H)=\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\mathbb P(H\mid T))=\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\pi(T)).
$$
Assuming that the distribution of $T$ has density $p$, 
$$
\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\pi(T))=\int_a^{+\infty}t\pi(t)p(t)\mathrm dt. 
$$
Likewise, 
$$
\mathbb P(H)=\mathbb E(\mathbb P(H\mid T))=\mathbb E(\pi(T))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\pi(t)p(t)\mathrm dt.
$$ 
Finally, indeed,
$$
\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_B\mid H)=\mathbb P(B)\frac{\displaystyle\int_a^{+\infty}t\pi(t)p(t)\mathrm dt}{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\pi(t)p(t)\mathrm dt}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I tried going this way but I got stuck on your second line. Why is $\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_H)=\mathbb E(T\mathbf 1_A\mathbb P(H\mid T))$?

Comment: For every sigma-algebra $G$ and random variables $U$ and $V$, if $U$ is $G$-measurable then $E(UV)=E(UE(V\mid G))$. Use this with $G=\sigma(T)$, $U=T\mathbf 1_A$ and $V=\mathbb 1_H$.

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out